# How to calculate the difference between of the elements in an array starting from the last up to the first in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

This is an array given:

```
arrayNum = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9];
arrayS = [];
for(var i=1, len = array1.length; i<len; i++){
    arrayS.push(arrayNum[i]-arrayNum[i-1]);
  }
console.log(arrayS);
```

This code calculates the difference between each two consecutive elements!
However I need to calculate the difference between elements starting from the last up to the first element what would be in this particular case 9-8-5-4-2-1 = -11?!

```
s1=0;
for(var j=array1[array1.length-1]; j>0; j--){
    s1 = s1 - array1[j];
  }
console.log(s1);
```

However this is not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original solution, you should iterate the index, rather than the element

```js
const arrayNum = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9];

s1 = arrayNum[arrayNum.length - 1];
for (var j = arrayNum.length - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
  s1 = s1 - arrayNum[j];
}
console.log(s1);
```

Or you could use reduce

```js
const arrayNum = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9];

const res = arrayNum.reduce(
  (acc, el, index) => acc + (index !== arrayNum.length - 1 ? -1 : 1) * el,
  0
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduceRight()` to calculate the difference from the end of the array.

Note: that reduce/reduceRight would throw an error when reducing an empty array without an initial value. I use a ternary to check the length, and if it's empty return [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

```js
const fn = arr =>
  arr.length ?
    arrayNum.reduceRight((s, n) => s - n) // if array is not empty
    :
    NaN // if array is empty

const arrayNum = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9];

const result = arrayNum.reduceRight((s, n) => s - n)

console.log(result);
```

For the for loop to work, you need to initialize `s1` without setting a value, and `j` with the last index. When calculating `s1` check if it's undefined, and initialize it with the current number. If it's not, subtract the current number:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9];

let s1;

for (let j = array1.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
  s1 = s1 === undefined ? array1[j] : s1 - array1[j];
}

console.log(s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expression 9-8-5-4-2-1 is equal to -(-9+8+5+4+2+1).

-9+8+5+4+2+1 is equal to (-(9*2) + (9+8+5+4+2+1)).

```js
const arrayNum = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9];

const res = -arrayNum.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num
, -arrayNum[arrayNum.length - 1] * 2)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with `var j=array1[array1.length-1];`, not correct index to start with in for-loop.

Try the while loop, should simplify for this case.

```js
array1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9];

s1 = array1[array1.length-1];
j = array1.length-1;

while (--j >= 0) s1 -= array1[j];

console.log(s1);
```